# Set value of variable with hyperlink php

Tags: php, html, database, hyperlink

I want to set the value of a column in my database by the link a user clicks.

```
<body>
Choose the position you would like your duo to primarily play:
<a href="/ADC%20Seek/ADC-Support.html">
Support
</a>&nbsp;
<a href="/ADC-Seek/ADC-Mid.html">
Mid Lane
</a>&nbsp;
<a href="/ADC-Seek/ADC-Top.html">
Top Lane
</a>&nbsp;
<a href="/ADC-Seek/ADC-Jungle.html">
Jungle
</a>
</body>
<?php
$seek= value set from link clicked
$query= "INSERT INTO mytable (seek) VALUES ('$seek')";  
?>
```

Comment: and you expect your php code to run in a .html file... how? You need to learn the basics of PHP and how you interact with a website.

Comment: I know that the php is another file... didn't think i needed to write out the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this, you can pass a variable into the URL using a GET but that would require you to change your page structure.

Simply add the insert on each page:

*ADC-Jungle.**php***

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'demo');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO db (column_name) VALUES ('Jungle');

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
```

For your purpose this is the simplest solution, but not necessarily the way I would do it.

**EDIT**

As Marc said, these need to be PHP files.